# onmouseover action not working...what should i do?

Tags: mouseover

```
 <span id="hintText_123" style="display:none">
          <table id="hintTable" style="width:100%;border:0px none;padding:0px;border-collapse:collapse;margin:0px;background-color:#7F9DB9;">
             <tr style=background-color:#56718A;>
             <td style="color:white;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;padding:2px">
                                        Title
              </td>
              <td style="width:5%;padding:2px">
              <img alt="" src="close.gif" style="width:15px;height:15px"  align=middle onclick=parent.hidetip()>
                                    </td></tr>
              <tr  style="background-color:#8CA7C0;"><td style="color:white;font-size:10px;padding:2px" colspan=2 >Description
                 </td>
               </tr>
               </table>
                        </span>
```

This is the table i want to display on mouseclick event of the below item

```
<span style="display:block;" onmouseout="toggleHelp('helpGrp_123',false,'group_field_name_123')" onclick="showhint(document.getElementById('hintTextGrp_123') , this, event, '380px')">
                                Hello!!!
</span>

</tr>
```

but the table is not getting displayed on clicking **Hello**!!!

Comment: provide the code for 'toggleHelp' method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function callMe()
{
    var tmp = document.getElementById("hintText_123");
    alert(tmp.style.display);
    tmp.style.display = 'block'; 
}
</script>
```

Call on onmousemove="callMe()"

Comment: You can call on mouse over and on click.